# How to get long text field in django models 1.3 with sql 2005

Tags: django, django-models

what is the field name that should be given in the models to get long text field.
I'm using django 1.3 and sql 2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your model write this

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

links

1)for reference [visit](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/) this.

2)and [this might](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/) be usefull

Comment: I want more memory than a char field (something like long text field)

Comment: 300-500 characters atleast

Comment: then you can use max_length=500 or TextField()

Comment: swetha mam can u do me a small favor?

Answer (score 1):

If you need longer text then this should help:

```
your_field = models.TextField("your field name")
```

see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#textfield